# TIWMenu and TIWRegion hides Submenus

Tags: delphi, delphi-2006, intraweb

When I put a TIWMenu and a TIWRegion on a TIWAppForm with

```
IWMenu.align := alTop;
IWRegion.align := alClient;
```

the submenu of IWMenu is hidden behind the region. That means, when I click on File, a submenu should come up with Open, Save, Save As ..., and it does, but I only see the upper border as the rest shows up behind the IWRegion.

I tried to change the z-order, but it does not help. Neither does setting the IWRegion.ClipRegion := False;

Does anybody have a clue what I do wrong?

I am using Delphi BDS4/2006 with IntraWeb 9.0.42, Windows Vista x64, and Firefox 3.5, IE8, and IE Tab in Firefox.

I drop the two components on the form, connect the main menu to IWMenu, and there the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the ServerController that used a style sheet. This prevented the z-index from being set by the application and therefore the z-order was wrong for the TIWMenu component.

Removing the style sheet resolved the problem. The style sheet had some IDs conflicting with IW.

Comment: It would have been great if you'd mentioned that this was not replicated with a simple test app (which would have lacked that style sheet).  *Test apps are key to tracking down bugs*.

Comment: Sorry, I happened to have made a test app, but my predecessor had changed the templates such that they by default had a style sheet.

Comment: Templates are usually helpful, but can make it harder to track problems.

Answer (score 0):

Could you be more specific about **your setup** (e.g. Windows version) and **steps to reproduce**?  Sounds like something wrong in how you've set this up.

**I can't reproduce this problem**, either in BDS2006 (IW ver 8) nor in RAD2009 (IW ver 10).

I started with a standalone IW application, dropped in a TIWMenu (Align=alTop), TIWRegion (Align=alClient), and TMainMenu (with a few menu and submenu items), and attached the TIWMenu to the TMainMenu.  Running this under Win XP sp3, I see the menu and submenu items just fine (over the IWRegion).